# SwiftUI List with @FocusState and focus change handling

Tags: swiftui

I want to use a `List`, `@FocusState` to track focus, and `.onChanged(of: focus)` to ensure the currently focused field is visible with `ScrollViewReader`. The problem is: when everything is setup together the `List` rebuilds constantly during scrolling making the scrolling not as smooth as it needs to be.

I found out that the `List` rebuilds on scrolling when I attach `.onChanged(of: focus)`. The issue is gone if I replace `List` with `ScrollView`, but I like appearance of `List`, I need sections support, and I need editing capabilities (e.g. delete, move items), so I need to stick to `List` view.

I used `Self._printChanges()` in order to see what makes the body to rebuild itself when scrolling and the output was like:

```
ContentView: _focus changed.
ContentView: _focus changed.
ContentView: _focus changed.
ContentView: _focus changed.
...
```

And nothing was printed from the closure attached to `.onChanged(of: focus)`. Below is the simplified example, the smoothness of scrolling is not a problem in this example, however, once the List content is more or less complex the smooth scrolling goes away and this is really due to `.onChanged(of: focus)` :(

**Question:** Are there any chances to listen for focus changes and not provoke the List to rebuild itself on scrolling?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    enum Field: Hashable {
        case fieldId(Int)
    }
    
    @FocusState var focus: Field?
    @State var text: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            let _ = Self._printChanges()
            ForEach(0..<100) {
                TextField("Enter the text for \($0)", text: $text)
                    .id(Field.fieldId($0))
                    .focused($focus, equals: .fieldId($0))
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: focus) { _ in
            print("Not printed unless focused manually")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not observe described behavior with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5. No output on scroll, on tap in any text field one "ContentView: _focus changed" and one "Not printed unless focused manually" are printed as expected.

Comment: @Asperi The idea is to NOT focus any field, just scroll the List, please. Let me know if you still don't see "ContentView: _focus changed." on scroll. Once a field gets focus there is really no output on scrolling. (Xcode 13.4.1 /iOS 15.5)

Comment: Yes, interesting effect... cannot say if it is a bug.

Comment: I noticed that ScrollView with LazyVStack give the same effect as List, so this has something to do with the dynamic nature of the view: rows are created on the fly and .focused modifier "changes" focus var which in turn due to presence of .onChange(of: focus) triggers rebuild... This is my theory :) But how to workaround it? I was thinking about attaching .onChange(of: focus) only when List is not scrolled, but I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: it seems that the problem is with `.onChange` there is definitely a bug with apple implementation, i bypassed it by returning to the deprecated API that still works perfectly in ver 16 (`.focusable(true, onFocusChange: { ... })`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to consider separation of list row content into standalone view and use something like focus "selection" approach. Having `FocusState` internal of each row prevents parent view from unneeded updates (something like pre-"set up" I assume).

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

```
struct ContentView: View {

    enum Field: Hashable {
        case fieldId(Int)
    }

    @State private var inFocus: Field?

    var body: some View {
        List {
            let _ = Self._printChanges()
            ForEach(0..<100, id: \.self) {
                ExtractedView(i: $0, inFocus: $inFocus)
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: inFocus) { _ in
            print("Not printed unless focused manually")
        }
    }

    struct ExtractedView: View {
        let i: Int
        @Binding var inFocus: Field?

        @State private var text: String = ""
        @FocusState private var focus: Bool     // << internal !!

        var body: some View {
            TextField("Enter the text for \(i)", text: $text)
                .focused($focus)
                .id(Field.fieldId(i))
                .onChange(of: focus) { _ in
                    inFocus = .fieldId(i)     // << report selection outside
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is not a solution, all the children views (ExtractedView) gets re-rendered and with large amount of views, scrolling becomes sluggish, does any one have a good solution for this ?

Comment: use printChanges to monitor the views being rendered by SwiftUI

`let _ = Self._printChanges()  // <<< ADD THIS TO SEE RE-RENDER`

has any one found a better solution to this ?

Answer (score 2):

if you add printChanges to the beginning of the body, you can monitor the views and see that they are being rendered by SwiftUI (all of them on each focus lost and focus gained)

```
   ...

var body: some View {
let _ = Self._printChanges()  // <<< ADD THIS TO SEE RE-RENDER

   ...
```

so after allot of testing, it seams that the problem is with `.onChange`, once you add it SwiftUI will redraw all the Textfields,

the only BYPASS i found is to keep using the deprecated API as it works perfectly, and renders only the two textfields (the one that lost focus, and the one that gained the focus),

so the code should look this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    enum Field: Hashable {
        case fieldId(Int)
    }
    
    // @FocusState var focus: Field? /// NO NEED
    @State var text: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            let _ = Self._printChanges()
            ForEach(0..<100) {
                TextField("Enter the text for \($0)", text: $text)
                    .id(Field.fieldId($0))
                //  .focused($focus, equals: .fieldId($0)) /// NO NEED
            }
        }
//      .onChange(of: focus) { _ in /// NO NEED
//          print("Not printed unless focused manually") /// NO NEED
//      } /// NO NEED
        .focusable(true, onFocusChange: { focusNewValue in
            print("Only textfileds that lost/gained focus will print this")
        })
    }
}
```